# Calling constructor overload when both overload have same signature

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, constructor, overloading

Consider the following class,

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int count)
    {
        /* .. */
    }

    public Foo(int count)
    {
        /* .. */
    }
}
```

Above code is invalid and won't compile. Now consider the following code,

```
class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(int count)
    {
        /* .. */
    }

    public Foo(T t)
    {
        /* .. */
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo<int> foo = new Foo<int>(1);
}
```

Above code is valid and compiles well. It calls *Foo(int count)*.

My question is, if the first one is invalid, how can the second one be valid? I know class *Foo<T>* is valid because T and int are different types. But when it is used like *Foo<int> foo = new Foo<int>(1)*, T is getting integer type and both constructor will have same signature right? Why don't compiler show error rather than choosing an overload to execute?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your question was hotly debated when C# 2.0 and the generic type system in the CLR were being designed. So hotly, in fact, that the "bound" C# 2.0 specification published by A-W actually has the wrong rule in it! There are four possibilities:

1) Make it illegal to declare a generic class that could POSSIBLY be ambiguous under SOME construction.  (This is what the bound spec incorrectly says is the rule.)  So your `Foo<T>` declaration would be illegal.

2) Make it illegal to construct a generic class in a manner which creates an ambiguity.  declaring `Foo<T>` would be legal, constructing `Foo<double>` would be legal, but constructing `Foo<int>` would be illegal.

3) Make it all legal and use overload resolution tricks to work out whether the generic or nongeneric version is better. (This is what C# actually does.)

4) Do something else I haven't thought of.

Rule #1 is a bad idea because it makes some very common and harmless scenarios impossible. Consider for example:

```
class C<T>
{
  public C(T t) { ... } // construct a C that wraps a T
  public C(Stream state) { ... } // construct a C based on some serialized state from disk
}
```

You want that to be illegal just because `C<Stream>` is ambiguous?  Yuck. Rule #1 is a bad idea, so we scrapped it.

Unfortunately, it is not as simple as that. IIRC the CLI rules say that an implementation is allowed to reject as illegal constructions that actually do cause signature ambiguities. That is, the CLI rules are something like Rule #2, whereas C# actually implements Rule #3. Which means that there could in theory be legal C# programs that translate into illegal code, which is deeply unfortunate.

For some more thoughts on how these sorts of ambiguities make our lives wretched, here are a couple of articles I wrote on the subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/04/05/569085.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/04/06/odious-ambiguous-overloads-part-two.aspx

Comment: Guess the third Foo<> at 2 has to be int

Comment: "legal C# programs that translate into illegal code"  How is that even a possibility?  I thought the translation results in a `newobj` instruction and a method token, where `Foo<T=int>.ctor(int)` and `Foo<T=int>.ctor(T)` have different method tokens.  So there is no ambiguity in the IL.  Did I miss something?

Comment: @BenVoigt: First, instead of "illegal code" it would have been more accurate had I said "unverifiable code" or "code with implementation-defined behaviour". The consequences of a generic construction which produces a signature collision are subtle. Suppose for instance we have two methods with the same signature, and wish to indicate in metadata that one of them is the implementation of a particular interface method. There's no metadata construct which can go in the method implementation table that disambiguates between two methods with the same signature. There are other similar odd cases.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You are likely right that in the specific case of constructors, there would not be a problem.

Answer (score 23):

There is no ambiguity, because the compiler will choose the most specific overload of `Foo(...)` that matches. Since a method with a generic type parameter is considered less specific than a corresponding non-generic method, `Foo(T)` is therefore less specific than `Foo(int)` when `T == int`. Accordingly, you are invoking the `Foo(int)` overload.

Your first case (with two `Foo(int)` definitions) is an error because the compiler will allow only one definition of a method with precisely the same signature, and you have two.

Comment: I checked the language specification, but it doesn't say generic parameters are less specific than concrete types. Non-generic methods are considered 'better' than generic methods however.

Comment: You're right, that wasn't phrased very well. I meant to say "a method with a generic type parameter...".

Comment: BTW, for the curious, I think the section Thorarin is talking about is §14.4.2.2, which defines "better function member".

Comment: I understand this. But IMO, compiler should warn as this type of behavior makes confusion.

Comment: Not sure how the compiler could do anything useful here by way of a warning - as soon as you defined Foo(T t) - all other single parameter methods with that name would fall foul of the sort of check you suggest.

Comment: It doesn't warn about this kind of behavior because it is exactly the intention of the language author that it be used this way.  The generic path is used for any data type the class instantiator wants, but when they instantiate the class with an int as the generic type the class has been given a special function that is assumed to be optimized or otherwise tailored for the int type.  This is a very basic part of the language, and thus not an error.

Comment: I agree. This is no more "confusing" than, say, "object o = 5". Should the compiler warn you every time it's taking advantage of an implicit but unambiguous assumption to make your life easier?

Answer (score 9):

Eric Lippert [blogged](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx) about this recently.

Comment: And, apparently, he's answered the question here as well.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that they do not both have the same signature - one is using generics while this other is not.

With those methods in place you could also call it using a non-int object:

```
Foo<string> foo = new Foo<string>("Hello World");
```