# How to create two constructor overloads, both taking only one string parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

For example, you want an object to be possibly initialised in two ways, using a file path and using a string. Normally both constructors should take one string parameter, `MyObject(string file)` and `MyObject(string content)`, but it is impossible to overload this way. What do you suggest?

*Edit*: In the first case, the file path is also needed, so please don't suggest a solution that reads the file content and just pass the content to the other constructor.

Comment: Wrap one of the string types in its own class, and accept that type as a parameter instead.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Hi, I think that merits to be an answer.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer because I think the one provided by Mark Byers is the best solution in this case. (I upvoted that one instead.) No reason to create an additional wrapper class when there's a type built in that will do the job instead. For more general applications, my suggestion is probably the way to go, however.

Comment: I would go for either the static factory method or create a constructor that accepts both arguments and throws an exception if both args are != null. I'm saying this because not always (my case - I have a similar problem), the types are really strings and I don't find it particularly elegant to throw in a new class that represents a string

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps you could change the first to accept a [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) instead:

```
class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(FileInfo file) { /* etc... */ }
    public MyObject(string content) { /* etc... */ }
}

...

MyObject o = new MyObject(new FileInfo(filename));
```

Comment: Or more generally, wrap one of the string types in its own class, and accept that type as a parameter instead (in this case the wrapper is FileInfo)

Answer (score 17):

I'm not a C# programmer but this looks like a job for the [static factory method](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx) pattern:

```
class MyObject {
  public static MyObject FromContent(string content) {
    return new MyObject(content);
  }

  public static MyObject FromFile(string path) {
    return new MyObject(ReadContentFromFile(path));
  }
}
```

Then you can do

```
MyObject object = MyObject.FromFile("/some/path");
```

which is even more readable than using a regular constructor.

Comment: in the second case, I still need the path, which I will lose if I use this pattern.

Comment: You have this problem anyway right? Why not have MyObject.GetPath() that returns null if MyObject was not created from a path?

Comment: @Louis: create a private setter for the path that MyObject.FromFile() can use to store that information, or have a private constructor overload that takes an additional dummy parameter to indicate the string is a path - these might be warts in the design, but since they're private, and the resulting public interface is nice and clean it might be a reasonable trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

Or create factory methods:

```
public static MyObject CreateByFilePath(string path){ ... }
public static MyObject CreateByContent(string content){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a factory?

```
class MyObjectProvider
{
   public static MyObject CreateByPath(string path) 
   { 
      return new MyObject
              {
                  Path = path;
              };

   }

   public static MyObject CreateByContent(string content) 
   { 
      return new MyObject
              {
                  Content = content;
              };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer this question. ::

[Calling constructor overload when both overload have same signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293201/calling-constructor-overload-when-both-overload-have-same-signature)

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyObject(Uri fileUri);
public MyObject(string content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take the contrarian approach and say don't do it.  The best of the solutions posted so far (use an alternate type such as FileInfo or Uri for one of the overloads) seems a bit hackish to me - goes against the principle of least surprise.

If you can construct using the content only without a filename, it follows that the filename is not essential.  And similarly if you can construct with a filename only it follows that the content is not essential.  Presumably you can subsequently set the missing filename/content later, e.g. by setting a property:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(fileName);
myObject.Content = ...

MyObject myObject = new MyObject(content);
myObject.FileName = ...
```

Instead of trying to fight it, choose one of your parameters as being the most important (fileName in the following example), and create two constructurs as follows:

```
public MyObject(string fileName) : this(fileName, null)
{
}

public MyObject(string fileName, string content)
{
    ... implementation
}
```

You can allow null to be passed for either or both parameters if it makes sense.  And you can insist that at least one is not null if that's appropriate:

```
public MyObject(string fileName, string content)
{
    if (fileName == null && content == null) throw new ArgumentException(...);
    ...
}
```

In short, don't use hacks to work around restrictions like this.